# Shortest path to basic install of VS2015 DirectX app

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2015

I have a C++ D3D11 project built in VS2015.  It would appear that vc-redistx86.exe does NOT contain everything I need for it to run.  To wit, all of the files such as api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll seem not to be installed by that redistributable.

My question then is twofold:

1. What do I need to install in order to get all of the files such as api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll, whereas the redist package seems to install only 4 dlls.
2. Is there an installer that can manage this without a week's learning curve?  I'd like to check a box for **"VS2015 Prerequisites"** and have it just happen.  It doesn't has to be free if it works well!  This is NOT a product recommendation question, it's a ease-of-use question; they can all do it at some level.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install all pending Windows Updates

   Go to Start – Control Panel – Windows Update
   Check for updates and install all pending updates, then restart the computer.
   After the restart repeat the steps above again until no more updates are available.
2. Download the Visual C++ Redistributable 2015
   For Windows 64-bit
   [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (64-bit)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe)
   For Windows 32-bit
   [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (32-bit)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe)
   Run the vcredist_x64.exe (64-bit) or vcredist_x86.exe (32-bit) and select Uninstall if already installed
3. Run the .exe again and select Install and restart the computer

See also [here](http://blog.spreendigital.de/2015/09/01/how-to-fix-the-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-error-for-delphi-10-seattle/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-open-office-file).