# api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing when opening Microsoft Office file

Tags: crt

I am facing this .dll library missing error:

> This programme can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
>   is missing. Try to reinstall this.

When I try to open an Microsoft Office file.

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

The default solution is to install [KB2999226](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226) of Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you! I've installed vc_redist.x64.exe but didn't installed any Windows Updates. Still, it did the trick.

Comment: I can verify this works.

I ran into the same problem and downloaded the Visual C++ Redistributable on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine, ran it, and it solved my problem. No restart needed.

Comment: @alireza, I'm getting this error when trying to start Apache. Is there any way to fix the `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` error **without** having to restart the server?

Comment: -1 for failed attribution. this looks like a copy and paste job from [here](https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0dll-is-missing-f2702.html) considering i can copy and paste this into SO's editor and get the exact same thing minus the links which only takes a couple of seconds to fix

Comment: I need this to run python, and uninstalling/installing those installers did nothing for me. Thinking I may need to reformat my pc at this point. When I did it earlier this year, I had trouble installing updates on a clean install, and Microsoft support had me enable some services to get it working.

Comment: @Memor-X I fixed it. (gave attribution and put in block quotes)

Comment: The solution is much simpler.  Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 download and install the missing runtime.

Comment: KB2999226 is actually a part of the VC++2015 redist.  You should be able to get the files you need from either one.

Comment: installing "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017 (64-bit)" fixed it without any requirement to reboot. Thanks

Comment: I've been dealing ith these bugs for a long time, and, although I'm absolutely certain I have 64 bit windows 8.1 installed on a 64 bit machine, I simply cannot install this KB update. Currently, it's telling me "this update is not applicable to your computer." I've had a variety of other issues pop up in this process as well. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: No solution for windows 7 Professional, its not working here! :(

Comment: @Anupam :  VC 2017 redistributable package is worked for me. I do have a doubt.  we are using binary(our application)  which is build with VS 2015, so is it correct fix to use 2017 redistributable package in order to resolve dll missing issue ?

Comment: What about Windows 10?

Comment: For me, installing vc_redist.x64.exe did not work, and installing this KB worked.

Answer (score 32):

While the answer from alireza is correct, it has one gotcha:

You can't install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 redist (runtime) unless you have Windows Update KB2999226 installed (at least on Windows 7 64-bit SP1).

Comment: Same with Windows 8.1

Comment: This is simply not true.  I just propped up a Win 7 SP1 x64 machine.  I confirmed KB2999266 has not been installed.  I downloaded vc_redist.x64.exe from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 and installed it without issues.  This also solves the problem the poster has by adding api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll  (and many other crt files) to %windir%\system32.

Comment: To add to @Algonaut's feedback.. The installer log for the 2015 redist shows `Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'`, meaning it carries and installs the KB2999226 update.

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 up to date. I try to install/uninstall the redistributable, but when I install I get error: "0x80242217 unspecified error."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I agree, that solution not working on my windows 7 professional ! :(

Answer (score 4):

Recursively update Windows 7 until it shows no more updates, using Windows Update check option in Windows 7.

Then download and install Visual C++ Redistributable vc_redist.x64.exe from the Windows website.

Then try to run Apache server.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete all temp files

   - search `%TEMP%`
   - delete all
2. Perform a clean boot. 
   see [How to perform a clean boot in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135)
3. Install `vc_redist.x64`
   see [Download Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
4. Restart without clean boot

Comment: Steps 1, 2 and 4 are completely unrelated to the topic at hand.

Answer (score 2):

This error is usually caused by the missing `Visual C++ Redistributable file`, which is a required dependency for most of the application on Windows Computer.

Download Visual C++ Redistributable from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145) and install it. After installing this, Reboot the system.

Link: [Visual C++ Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Answer (score 1):

In case nothing of the previous answers worked, add one of these paths to your PATH environment variable:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x86
```

Of course, make sure they exist first and that they contain the DLL files needed.
If they don't exist, try installing "Windows Universal CRT SDK" from the Visual Studio 2015 or Visual Studio 2017 installer.

Answer (score 0):

if anybody unable to update windows online, I suggest you go to http://download.wsusoffline.net/ and download Most recent version.

Then install update generator -> select your operating system. and hit START, just wait few minutes let him download updates and complete all it's process. hope this help.

[image: Image of Offline update generator]

Comment: Yes, this is the good old [c't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%27t) / Heise offline updater.

Answer (score 0):

This is old post and I am sorry but even installing of KB2999226 will not help if you don't have  [April 2014 update rollup for Windows RT 8.1, Windows 8.1, and Windows Server 2012 R2 (2919355)](https://support.microsoft.com/help/2919355) update package.
Without it the installation of KB2999226 returns error "The update is not applicable to your computer". Typically you will get this problem if you have some offline envinroment for example dev virtual machines without access to the WSUS or Windows Update services and old ISO images of Windows 8.1, Server 2012 R2.