# The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing while starting Apache server on my computer

Tags: php, apache, perl, dll

In order to quickly set up my PHP/Perl development environment, I installed [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). Specifically, I attempted to install using: `xampp-win32-7.0.1-0-VC14-installer`.

When I started the program, I ran into an error related to a `dll` file. I also tried the suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-open-office-file) that sounded like fixes to the same problem.

The problem is still not fixed after trying the above.

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing when open office file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-open-office-file)

Comment: The simple and best solution is to downgrade and download PHP 5.6.39 Or PHP 7.0.3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was facing the same issue.
After many tries below solution worked for me.

Before installing VC++ install your windows updates.
  1. Go to Start - Control Panel - Windows Update
  2. Check for the updates.
  3. Install all updates.
  4. Restart your system.

After that you can follow the below steps.

@ABHI KUMAR

Download the Visual C++ Redistributable 2015

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (64-bit)

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (32-bit)

(Reinstal if already installed) then restart your computer or use windows updates for download auto.

For link download https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=48145.

Comment: i run the window update and installed Visual C++ Redistribution 2015 but aborted this installation because same program is installed in my computer and still not resolved the problem.

Comment: @ABHI KUMAR try download it and open again select repair, if still don't work try reinstal.

Comment: it gives the same problem in installation after selecting repair

Comment: @ABHI KUMAR okay are you instal both or only 1? if your computer 64 try instal 32bit too, if only 32 try unsintal then open Ccleaner then try Run Cleaner & Fix Issues Registry then restart, after that try instal again. should be work.

Comment: my system is 64 ,installed 32 bit , finally installed the older version 5.6.12 and its working fine. thanks dear

Comment: That link is now invalid.

Comment: from where you downloaded old verson i have same issue

Comment: Same as Neel Kamal Neeraj here. With XAMPP 7.1.1, same error, no Visual Studio file did for me, with 64bits, tried 32 and neither. Then downloaded and installed XAMPP 5.6.30 and this one works.

Answer (score 10):

Download the Visual C++ Redistributable 2015

Updated links to VC++  file:

[For Windows 64-bit](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe)

[For Windows 32-bit](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe)