# How to start Apache in Xampp if it is showing the following error?

Tags: xampp

When I start Xampp, it comes with error:

> The program can't start because `api-ms-win--crt-runtine-l1-1-0.dll`
>   is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix
>   this problem

as seen in the image below.

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740438/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-whi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing while starting Apache server on my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740438/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-whi)