# My program doesn't run on some PCs

Tags: c++, opencv, deployment, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I'm working in a project building an application with Computer Vision using C++, OpenCV and Visual Studio. I'm no expert in deploying programs to use them on other PCs.

I've made a program which I need to distribute to a certain amount of people and I can't make it work on all the computers I'd like to. The program was written using Visual Studio 2015, it's an MFC Project and the code is written in C++ since I'm using OpenCV.

When it was finished, I tried to run it on another computer and I realized that it won't open. I looked on the Internet and found out that I needed to statically link the libraries, so I did it. Also, when I was looking for information, I found that Visual Studio 2015 builds its projects so you can run the programs on machines with Win7 to Win10. When I learnt that, I tried to open it on PCs running Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10. I tested my program in like 20 computers, give or take.

The results? I couldn't make it work for Windows 7, the error ***ucrtbase.terminate api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll*** showed every time I tried to open it. It also didn't open in one machine with Windows 8 without showing any error message, but it **DID** open on **most** of the machines with Win 8.1 and Win 10. The thing is that "**most**"; there were some PCs (with Win 8.1 and 10) that I couldn't open my program on. I found that sometimes it would show up in the Task Manager for less than a second and then disappear. The most stressful thing is that it doesn't tell me what the problem is, it doesn't show any error message. It just won't open.

I tried using Dependency Walker (both on my PC and one of those that I couldn't run my program on) to see if there's something missing and I got a reeaaally long list of files that the system couldn't find, here's an example: 
[List 1/11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n8UM.png). Something curious is that my program executes just well on my computer and on those I **could** open it, even though Dependency Walker (DW) tells me that there might be a problem with it. This indicates me that DW is not finding the exact error I'm having.

Another thing I've tried is to compare the things I have installed on my computer and install them on the one I want to execute my program on. I tried installing .NET Framework 4.6.1 just because VS 2015 says that my project was built using it (and I have it installed in my PC and that other one doesn't. Also I tried with .NET 4.6.1 SDK). Nothing changed.

Comment: Part of your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-open-office-file

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that :D

Comment: Distributing OpenCV C++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744112/package-opencv-dll-to-distribute-c-dll

Answer (score 0):

Just look here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms235299.aspx

The quick-and-dirty way would be to copy the DLLs from your redist directory. For my MS VS 2013 it is hidden under the VS installation directory in:

```
VC\redist\x86
```

or

```
VC\redist\x64
...
```

which depends on your application.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I've already done that by installing **VCRedist_x64** on the computer I want to run the program. Actually, when I send the program I do it including that **exe** and some instructions about what to do step by step in order to run it. I will try to "hard-copy" the files from my computer hoping it works.