# How many Visual C++ Redistributables do I need to get this application to run?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-7, windows-7-x64, unity-game-engine

Last night, I downloaded Unity to start developing games with my brother. The installer also gave me Visual Studio 2015 and MonoDevelop, which I gather is basically a slightly modified Visual Studio.

This morning I discovered the problem: MonoDevelop will open, but Visual Studio won't. It always came up with a pop-up box saying **"The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer."**

According to [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-open-office-file), I need to download the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015. But before doing that, I decided to check if I already had it, just in case.

I opened "Programs and Features" and beheld that I already had nine other Visual C++ Redistributables installed on my machine. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKqFf.png) shows the list.

[image: This image]

Included are the 2010, 2012, 2013, and 2015 redistributables for both x86 and x64. I don't know if this is typical or not but it certainly seems excessive.

Despite all these, my Visual Studio still won't open. Do I need to install another one? I'm happy to do that if I need to; *I just want to start coding.*

---

(I also had this same problem with Microsoft Office 365 before I just gave up and downloaded Microsoft Office 2013 instead, which works fine. Perhaps it's a problem with my machine? I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, for what it's worth.)

Comment: have you tried the universal C runtime (and the 2015, the other ones are not required)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to install the [Universal C Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50410)

> The Windows Update package on this page allows Windows desktop
>   applications that depend on the Windows 10 Universal CRT release to
>   run on Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1
>   S14.

Extract the `WindowsUCRT.zip` and install the `Windows6.1-KB3118401-x64.msu` (note if you get a hang at "Searching for updates on this computer", [cancel the install, stop the WU service and try again to install the update](https://superuser.com/a/1044548/174557)).

Comment: Works now! Thank you. Does this mean I can uninstall all the pre-2015 VC++ redistributables?

Comment: there are other tools that depend on the others and they only take a few MB space on HDD so leave them installed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again!