# api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing error on Apache start up xampp

Tags: apache, visual-studio, xampp, windows-8.1

I'm running windows 8.1
Ive attempted to download Visual Studio 2015, all forms including the redistributable. Ive attempted to update windows with the control panel prompts to no avail. I'm out of options. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing when opening Microsoft Office file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file)

Comment: install the Univeral C Runtime: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows