# ASP.Net Core 2.0 IIS error on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed :

dotnet-runtime-2.0.0-win-x64.exe
dotnet-sdk-2.0.0-win-x64.exe
DotNetCore.2.0.0-WindowsHosting.exe

On command prompt if I type dotnet, this appears:

```
api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll missing
```

On IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2 ASP.Net core 2.0 is returning this:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
>
> Common causes of this issue:
>
> The application process failed to start The application process
>   started but then stopped The application process started but failed to
>   listen on the configured port
>
> Troubleshooting steps:
>
> Check the system event log for error messages Enable logging the
>   application process' stdout messages Attach a debugger to the
>   application process and inspect
>
> For more information visit:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681

On Windows Logs, this appears:

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/CRUD' with physical root
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebAPI\CRUD\' failed to start process with
>   commandline 'dotnet .\CRUD.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : c0000135.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems that the Windows was not updated on the Server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core 0x80004005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857702/asp-net-core-0x80004005)

Comment: I requested another virtual machine from the technical staff, now with Windows Server 2016, everything updated and restarted, then all works fine.