# I am getting error while opening KDevelop

Tags: kdevelop

Recently I have installed KDevelop on my Windows7 32bit OS, and after installing when I try to open it I am getting an error. Actually, when I try to open KDevelop it says that `**api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll**` is missing, after getting that error I have downloaded that (**api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll**) file from **www.dll-files.com**, then after, I pasted it in D:/Programs Files/KDevelop/bin/ and now after doing that all again I am getting a new error that `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll is either not designed to run on Windows or contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administration or the software vendor for support.` any suggestion that get me out from this hell ?

Comment: It is pretty strange, because we package MSVC redist into KDevelop installer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you [don't have the appropriate Visual C++ Redistributable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33274879/1559401).

Also I would strongly advise **against** downloading DLL files even from seemingly legit web sites. Missing libraries are a symptom of something larger missing or corrupted.

Comment: I was uninstalled the previous as you have stated in your answer, then I goto the Setup which i was downloaded from the link which you have given but unfortunatly when I re-install it is says an error, the error code is something like this :- `0x80240017`. Can you please tell why it happens!

Comment: See [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_store/some-apps-from-the-windows-store-will-not-download/8e6ac08d-96d3-48ef-9bd1-bf86f1cfb8f6?db=5). Other than that I'm without a clue. Btw do you mind me asking why you would install a usually Linux-used IDE on a Windows system when there are a lot of IDEs that are more suitable for this task?

Comment: Okay! Thanks for your suggestion.