# api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing when opening Adobe Muse cc 2017

Tags: crt

Recently I am installed the Adobe Muse cc 2017.

I am facing this .dll library missing error:

> This programme can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing. Try to reinstall ....

When I try to open it. I am searching a lot in several sites but I couldn't find the solution. They said that you should installing the Windows Updates and Visual C++ Redistributable. As an example see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33274879/5862249). I installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2005-2017 32 and 64 bit, Adobe air, Java runtime environment and the final versions of such programs. I downloaded Adobe Muse cc 2017 from several sites again but this problem not solved. This problem occur even in the portable version of my program. 
How do I solve that?

Comment: Are you running Windows 7? Your link says Windows 7 require KB2999266. Did you do that?
 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49077

Comment: @StephenQuan, My Windows is 8.1.