# Apache not running in xampp

Tags: php, apache, visual-c++, windows-7, xampp

I installed xampp 7.1.2 in my windows 7 computer and after installing it when i try to run apache i get following error -

> the program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is
>   missing from your computer. try reinstalling the program to fix this
>   problem.

I reinstalled but no progress.

I posted a topic for this problem in apachefriends.com forum and they said me to have "MS visual c++ 2015(x86) 14.0.24.." installed, which i already had installed. I uninstalled existing this software in my computer and reinstalled this mentioned software but still i can't run apache in xampp control panel, i am getting same error as i wrote above!!.

I searched through web about this problem but did not find similar one. so how should i proceed??

Comment: Basic but worth checking, are you running it as admin?

Comment: nope not working

Answer (score 1):

Try following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33274879/2350423) here on SO. 
After installing, search for that dll to verify that it exist somewhere.

If not, it's worth trying this:
Check with [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) where xampp is looking for that dll, and then download the dll and put it in the place it's looking for.

Comment: very hard tasks lol in the linked question's correct answer they said to update windows!, i may try that but others not makes sense as i already have vc++ .... software installed. As u said i searched my computer and found that file under c:/program files/mozilla firefox now what?

Comment: so u saying i use procman to see where xampp search for that file ? but how i check with that procmon software? look like u suggesting hack but after all does that work properly sooner or later?

Comment: procmon could help you find the problem, and maybe then you could solve it. It's not going to fix it by it self (it's not what it does). If you find where xampp is looking and what is missing for it to work - you can try and manually fix it (by moving files)

Comment: but how i use procmon to see where xampp finding that file to place the file there?

Comment: There are a lot of examples and tutorials. [This for example](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb469930). You can [search for more](https://www.google.com/search?q=procmon+how+to+use&oq=procmon+how+to+use)

Comment: well in procmon i found that dll name by the httpd.exe process and saw the path so i copied that dll to that path here c:/xampp/apache/bin but now i getting this error = 'the procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll' . now what hack haha?

Comment: In which path you have installed it?

Comment: Sorry wat path u talking about? I installed xampp in c drive and as i wrote in my last comment, i placed that dll file in bin folder.

Comment: I'm asking since in xampp installation it suggested (to me at least) not to install it in program files, since it might result access problems. So to verify - it's not in program files, correct?

Comment: OH, missed that part in the comment above 

Comment: ok lolz i found out the problem, from web i saw that if i install win 7 service pack 1 then if i install vc++2015 well then this problem not coming.

Comment: Great! glad you found it