# MongoDB not running in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, mongodb

I have installed .msi file for mongodb but when I am running mongod.exe I am getting below error message in prompt.
[image]

Comment: Did you try reinstalling?
[This thread might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file)

Comment: Yes , I have tried that solution already.

Comment: Hi Nishant, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of including a screenshot of your error message, you would make your question better if you copied and pasted the error text directly into your question - that makes it easier for everybody to read, and in particular it is easier to be found by a search and easier for devices such as screen readers.
Images may make a question better, but it's best practice to try and make the question understandable even without them.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to installation directory (c:\...\mongodb\3.0\bin)
2. type mongod
3. in another terminal do step 1. and type mongo..

Comment: I am doing the same but when I am typing the command a windows alert box showing the error message as I have attached in the question.

Comment: dont type mongod.exe type mongod from ..\bin\ folder