# Is it possible to run an executable compiled with PyInstaller without installing the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages?

Tags: python

I have .exe compiled from python file using PyInstaller the .exe file work good on win10 but it cause error (the program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-I1-1-0.dll is missing from you computer) when run it on win7 or win8.1 machines.

Comment: Here are some pointers: [\[SO\]: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing when opening Microsoft Office file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file). Would it be possible instructing _PyInstaller_ to link to the static _vcruntime*_ version when building the executable?

Answer (score 1):

actually the only way to run the python files with out installing c++ packages is to compile your python script with python 3.4

install python 3.4 on your computer and :

1.install pypiwin32 version 219(its needed for installing pyinstaller): `pip install pypiwin32==219`

2.installing pyinstaller version 3 : `pip install pyinstaller==3.0`

and have fun with your compiled code :)