# How to start Mongo DB server from Windows?

Tags: mongodb

I have installed MongoDB 3.6.3 on my Window 8.1(64 bit) machine. I have created the path data/db too but when I tried to start mongodb using the command 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin', it is not starting. It showing a message "the program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer". Anyone help me to start Mongo DB server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must fix dll problem first. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file may be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD
nevigate to `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin` [Your mongodb installed location]

Then run command as `mongod --dbpath E:\sangram\mongo_workspace --port 27017`

**[E:\sangram\mongo_workspace]** is my local directory where i'll store my mongodb data

Comment: I am getting message as "the program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer". Can you please explain how to fix this problem?

Comment: i think you need to update your windows. or mannually need to install this `.dll` file. https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-missing-error-solved/ check this url

Comment: It needed not only above mentioned dll but many more different dlls however i have added all these dlls in "C:\Windows\System32". Now its working fine. Thanks.