# Error arising after Python.exe installation

Tags: python

After the installation of Python and opening the exe file, the following error is displayed: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll. I've attached a screenshot of the screen. Even after reinstalling Python, the error re-appears. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Don't see an attached image/screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing when opening Microsoft Office file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file)

Answer (score 0):

Found your error [here](https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/245). Seems like installing [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49984) could solve your problem.