# Running .net core 2.1 web api from command line in Virtual windows server

Tags: .net-core, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

I have created a virtual windows 2012 R2 server using hyper-V. I am new to hyper V and no sure if asking the question right.
I have added a .netcore website to ISS. When I try to launch it from cmd prompt using : dotnet exampleProj.dll. I am getting an error as below.

[image]

I have tried:

1) Downloading the dll and installing it to C:\Windows\SysWOW64

2) Installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable.

3) Tried to download from https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows. But was getting an when trying to install error saying "The update is not applicable to your computer"

The programs installed on server,
[image]

Comment: The problem is your windows 2012 R2 out updated. You need run Windows Update to latest then that would fix. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file

Comment: @Khai, I tried to install it as mentioned above I was getting error "The update is not applicable to your computer", not sure if its because it is a virtual machine.

Comment: No, I mean firstly you run windows update. Your Windows server need to be updated before install these very new softwares such as new Netcore

Comment: @Khai, I checked for updates, but there are no new updates available.

Comment: Yes, I know, I met this problem on my Windows Server 2012 R2 and I did not see any updates also. But I continue to check in the next time, that allow me update windows and now I can install new software. Which build version of your Windows 2012 R2?